# Can anyone explain why my post api is not working?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

So, I was creating a blog API using Node,Express and Mongo. I was successfully able to create login and register part. But while coding the api for posts. I am getting and error. And I am not able to work this out.

**This is my index.js file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();

const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
const userRoute = require('./routes/users');
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts');

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.use('/api/auth', authRoute);
app.use('/api/users', userRoute);
app.use('api/posts', postRoute);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Backend is running');
});
```

**This is my post schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    photo: {
      type: String,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    categories: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

**Posts.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const User = require('../models/User');
const Post = require('../models/Post');

//CREATE POST
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const newPost = new Post(req.body);
  try {
    const savedPost = await newPost.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedPost);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//UPDATE POST

//DELETE POST

//GET POST

module.exports = router;
```

[This is the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdALQ.png)
[Ths is the error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD0Ok.png)

The api is clearly isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js file try to change

```
app.use('api/posts', postRoute);
```

with this code-

```
app.use('/api/posts', postRoute);
```

and just lemme know if this works or not.. if didn't work just lemme know. I will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much Varun. Such a lame mistake by me.